# where can I find internal storage on emulator

Tags: android, macos

on my os x laptop I have android sdk installed into /Users/user/dv/android-sdk-utd. But where there is emulator's files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file-explorer to show the content of your eulator. Even you can pull or push file from emulator. Please follow this link

You can see the directory structure of emulator which is as same as phone.You can explore internal as well external storage of emulator.

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/24/how-to-add-files-like-images-inside-your-emulator-in-android/

Thanks